# Python: Get Geometry Node Instances

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, instances

I would like to get Geometry Node Instances through Python. Instance Mesh, Position, Rotation, Scale.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an example in the docs for how to get instances from the dependency graph:
https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html#dependency-graph-iterate-over-all-object-instances

You can filter the [object_instances](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html#bpy.types.Depsgraph.object_instances) list by checking if the [parent](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.DepsgraphObjectInstance.html#bpy.types.DepsgraphObjectInstance.parent) property of the instance matches your source object. Use the [matrix_world](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.DepsgraphObjectInstance.html#bpy.types.DepsgraphObjectInstance.matrix_world) property to get the transform of the instance.

**UPDATE:**
Here's an example for how to get instances from specific geometry nodes objects. Note that to identify the correct parent you actually have to check against the **evaluated object in the depsgraph** rather than the original object.

[image]

```
import bpy

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
objA = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
objB = bpy.data.objects["Plane"]
evalA = objA.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
evalB = objB.evaluated_get(depsgraph)

instA = [inst for inst in depsgraph.object_instances if inst.is_instance and inst.parent == evalA]
instB = [inst for inst in depsgraph.object_instances if inst.is_instance and inst.parent == evalB]

print("Total instances: {}, A: {}, B: {}".format(len(depsgraph.object_instances), len(instA), len(instB)))
```

Comment: I've added an example file and some clarifications, hope it helps.

Comment: Alright, thanks :)

Comment: Amaizing, thanks a lot! Are you sure that we need to check "inst.is_instance"? As object_instances is a list of instances I suppose.

Comment: Also, istead of "inst.parent == evalA" I would use "inst.parent is evalA".

Comment: The object_instances list also contains regular objects, they count as a single instance of themselves. In my test file the 2 meshes, the camera, and the default light add 4 extra instances to the list. You probably don't need to check is_instance if you are also filtering by parent though.

Comment: @lukas_t : when I iterate on instA, all matrix_world have the same value. All instA[i].object.name is also wrong, seems to be the name of another object in scene (for example apply the node tree to the default cube, name is "Camera", and matrix_world is transform of the Camera.