# Is it possible to export 'Instances' data from Spreadsheet viewer?

Tags: export, geometry

Until patch https://developer.blender.org/D12546 is available, is there an *existing*, alternate method (e.g. third party add on, python script) for exporting the geometry node instance positions from the spreadsheet viewer?

[image: Desired Output Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints a list of positions of the instances of the selected object:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C

dg = C.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
eval_ob = C.object.evaluated_get(dg)
instances = [i for i in dg.object_instances if i.is_instance and i.parent == eval_ob]

positions = []

for instance in dg.object_instances:
    if instance.is_instance and instance.parent == eval_ob:
        positions.append(instance.matrix_world.translation)
        
print(*positions, sep="\n")
```

See also: [Python: Get Geometry Node Instances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/266022/60486)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, Markus!