# How to export Blender spreadsheet data into .csv file without applying GN?

Tags: python, modifiers, geometry-nodes, linked-data, spreadsheet

[image]

I created this geometry in Blender GN, and I need to export the 3d coordinates of a list of points(These points are not on the input geometry), the data is already shown in the "Blender spreadsheet--Evaluated--point cloud-point-position" section. How can I export them as .csv or even text?

Comment: Does https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274936/is-it-possible-to-export-instances-data-from-spreadsheet-viewer help?

Comment: Hi, I‘ve tried the solution before, It gives me a list with one Vector(0,0,0). It's understandable because I didn't have more instances in my scene. I'm sure there is a way just similar to that solution. I've tried but no luck. the patch https://developer.blender.org/D12546, could perfectly solve my problem, but it hasn't been created/realised as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a workaround, as I don't believe this data is exposed to the python API yet. However it does get you the coordinates of your points in a csv file.

The one thing you'll need to add is a 'points to vertices' node, as python doesn't have access to 'points', but DOES have access to vertices.

After adding this node, you can use the following script to create a csv file with the coordinates of each vertex of the selected object. This doesn't really fix your problem if you wanted needed to keep your points as points, or if you wanted to exclude certain vertices (you may be able to do that with a stored attribute). Hope this helps!

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import bpy
import csv
import os

m = bpy.context.object.evaluated_get(bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()).to_mesh()

# Get the path to the current Blender file
blend_file_path = bpy.data.filepath

# Get the directory of the Blender file
blend_dir = os.path.dirname(blend_file_path)

# Construct the absolute path to the "data.csv" file
data_file_path = os.path.join(blend_dir, "data.csv")


def append_to_csv(filepath, x, y, z):
    # Check if the file exists
    file_exists = os.path.isfile(filepath)

    # Open the file in append mode
    with open(filepath, 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)

        # If the file doesn't exist, write the header
        if not file_exists:
            writer.writerow(['x', 'y', 'z'])

        # Write the values to the file
        writer.writerow([x, y, z])
        

for i in range(0, len(m.vertices)):
    v = m.vertices[i].co
    append_to_csv(data_file_path,v[0],v[1],v[2])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I need!